# Facebook login with different layouts

Tags: android, facebook

I have a facebook login code but the problem is it has the login button and profile page details in the same layout. I want to go to a different layout on successful login. Any help in this matter will be much appreciated.

```
MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    Button share,details;
    ShareDialog shareDialog;
    LoginButton login;
    ProfilePictureView profile;
    Dialog details_dialog;
    TextView details_txt;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        login = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        profile = (ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.picture);
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share);
        details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.details);
        login.setReadPermissions("public_profile email");
        share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        details.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        details_dialog = new Dialog(this);
        details_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_details);
        details_dialog.setTitle("Details");
        details_txt = (TextView)details_dialog.findViewById(R.id.details);
        details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                details_dialog.show();
            }
        });


        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
            RequestData();
            share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                    share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    details.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    profile.setProfileId(null);
                }
            }
        });
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().build();
                shareDialog.show(content);

            }
        });
        login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
                    RequestData();
                    share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            }
        });

    }
    public void RequestData(){
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

                JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                try {
                    if(json != null){
                        String text = "<b>Name :</b> "+json.getString("name")+"<br><br><b>Email :</b> "+json.getString("email")+"<br><br><b>Profile link :</b> "+json.getString("link");
                        details_txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
                        profile.setProfileId(json.getString("id"));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }



}
```

Comment: on successful login get all required data and pass it in bundle to other activity

Comment: Sorry I'm new. Where should I add the Intent? In login.registerCallback() ?

Comment: onSuccess of callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass your `Intent` after successful fetching of data in onCompleted method of GraphRequest like this :

```
public void RequestData(){
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

            JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
            try {
                if(json != null){
                    String text = "<b>Name :</b> "+json.getString("name")+"<br><br><b>Email :</b> "+json.getString("email")+"<br><br><b>Profile link :</b> "+json.getString("link");
                    details_txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
                    profile.setProfileId(json.getString("id"));
//    Pass your Intent Here 
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
                @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                         Log.d("Error ", "Error");
                        // here you have can handle if any error occur 
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.d("cancle ", "cancle");
                        // This method is called if user interrupt data fetching 
                    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kapil. I added my Intent as you suggested and it works good. But for a second or 2 before changing layout, it shows the "Log out" button on the same page and then the Intent changes the layout. Can I do something to remove this ? @Kapil.

Comment: Yes on click of login button (login.setOnClickListener) set its Visibility as Invisible login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: I can do that but the whole layout is still visible for a couple of seconds. I want when the facebook access page vanishes, the first layout also changes to new layout due to intent. Currently it stays on the 1st page for 2 sec and then changes to new layout. @Kapil.

Comment: This is happening as you are fetching data from JsonObject and then passing Intent , to resolve your issue you can manage alpha of your layout  ,set alpha to 100 when on create Activity and when  onCompleted is called set alpha to 0.

Comment: Any other way for this? Like fetching data from JsonObject in the second layout.... @Kapil.

Comment: yes pass your intent on successful login onSuccess method of login.registerCallback and then call RequestData() method there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99188/discussion-between-somnath-pal-and-kapil-rajput).